# How to convert date into text in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Consider the df

```
 Dates
 Sun 22nd Jul
 Sat 20th Jul
```

How do I change this into text format ? The year was not given is there a way to make this into text?

i tried

```
df %>% mutate(Date2 = as.Date(Dates, "%w%b%m"))
```

but each col came up as NA

Comment: (1) It is already text. (2) If you want to guess the year (i.e., those dates where it is actually the DOW suggested), it will still be a guess. Do you know a range of years from which this data is extracted? (3) Data like this is frustrating and poor; if this is from a source, consider asking them to give it in an unambiguous format (4-digit year, perhaps even just `%Y-%m-%d` format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly-contrived method to *infer* the year based on matching the day-of-week that is provided.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- tibble(Dates = c("Sun 22nd Jul", "Sat 20th Jul"))
guesses <- df %>%
  mutate(
    rn = row_number(),
    DOW = gsub(" .*", "", Dates),
    Date1 = gsub("(?<=[0-9])(st|nd|rd|th)\\b", "", Dates, perl = TRUE),
    Date1 = gsub("^\\D*(?=[0-9])", "", Date1, perl = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  crossing(
    Year = 2000:2020
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Date2 = as.Date(paste(Date1, Year), format = "%d %b %Y"),
    DOW2 = format(Date2, format = "%a")
  ) %>%
  filter(DOW == DOW2)
guesses
# # A tibble: 7 x 7
#   Dates           rn DOW   Date1   Year Date2      DOW2 
#   <chr>        <int> <chr> <chr>  <int> <date>     <chr>
# 1 Sat 20th Jul     2 Sat   20 Jul  2002 2002-07-20 Sat  
# 2 Sat 20th Jul     2 Sat   20 Jul  2013 2013-07-20 Sat  
# 3 Sat 20th Jul     2 Sat   20 Jul  2019 2019-07-20 Sat  
# 4 Sun 22nd Jul     1 Sun   22 Jul  2001 2001-07-22 Sun  
# 5 Sun 22nd Jul     1 Sun   22 Jul  2007 2007-07-22 Sun  
# 6 Sun 22nd Jul     1 Sun   22 Jul  2012 2012-07-22 Sun  
# 7 Sun 22nd Jul     1 Sun   22 Jul  2018 2018-07-22 Sun
```

(Choosing 2000 as a starting point was arbitrary. It should be informed on your knowledge of the data source.)

If we assume that the most-recent one is what is needed, then

```r
guesses %>%
  arrange(desc(Date2)) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 2 x 7
#   Dates           rn DOW   Date1   Year Date2      DOW2 
#   <chr>        <int> <chr> <chr>  <int> <date>     <chr>
# 1 Sun 22nd Jul     1 Sun   22 Jul  2018 2018-07-22 Sun  
# 2 Sat 20th Jul     2 Sat   20 Jul  2019 2019-07-20 Sat
```

If we assume that having them all in the same year is critical, then

```r
guesses %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  filter(all(df$Dates %in% Dates)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

(Unfortunately, it shows nothing for this data, so highly unlikely.)

There are certainly other methods of *inference* one might try to guess the hidden years.

From here, all you need then is the `Date2` column.